# render chart with different bars

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm getting started with KQL and I can't  figure out how to display different counts as different bars in my query.

```
dependencies
| extend contextId = tostring(customDimensions["ProcessFunction-Context ID"])
| extend rowsCount = toint(customDimensions["ProcessFunction-Context ID|RowsCount"])
| extend processedCount = toint(customDimensions["ProcessFunction-RowsInjected"])
| where contextId  == "b5edc9c5-1fd3-4c02-89dc-e446d28dec6f"
| project  rowsCount, processedCount
| render columnchart
```

basically I want to display rowsCount and processedCount in different columns in the chart, but they are being displayed together:

[image]

The expected result is something like this:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to 'solve' it:

```
dependencies
| extend contextId = tostring(customDimensions["ProcessFunction-Context ID"])
| extend rowsCount = toint(customDimensions["ProcessFunction-Context ID|RowsCount"])
| extend processedCount = toint(customDimensions["ProcessFunction-RowsInjected"])
| where contextId  == "b5edc9c5-1fd3-4c02-89dc-e446d28dec6f"
| project rowsCount, processedCount, timestamp
| render columnchart kind=unstacked
```

Comment: How did you change the colors in the columnchart?